# Detect iOS version lower than iOS 8 php

Tags: php, ios, safari

If been searching for a while but don't find any good solution. I need to detect the iOS version so that I can decide whether to show some part of the website or not. Additionally this content should be shown on any non MobileSafari browser.

So basically:
If iOS and if version < iOS 8 than do nothing;
Else show content

Comment: you should be able to use user agent string for that, no?

Comment: http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/os-detail?os=iOS%208

Comment: Now I feel stupid, thanks!

Comment: An addition, that is the user agent I need but now I need code to detect whether it's iOS or not (if not than show) and then I need to detect if the version is >= 8.

Comment: I think all iPhones have in their user agent the word iPhone

Comment: iPads have the word iPad in UA and iPods have the word iPod in UA... should be simple enough

Comment: Yes, this really helped me on my way, give me a moment to get it done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lots of thanks to @Lucas1 and @Daan I came up with this :)

```
<?php 
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone') || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad' ) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPod' ) !== false){
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'OS 8_0') !== false) {
    echo "content here on ios";
    }
    else{echo "sorry no content for you";}
    }

else {
    echo "content here";
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP_USER_AGENT will return the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

If you are trying to detect iOS 8, do the following:

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone OS 8_0') !== false) { };?>
```

Comment: This was what I tried in the first place, but it needs to show the content for every browser (Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE, Firefox) except for MobileSafari on devices running anything less than iOS 8. I'll clarify my post :)