# How to detect iOS version with php?

Tags: php, ios, iphone

How to detect iOS version with php. I  am trying to work  with  the solution `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but it display:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

I want to display `OS 8_0` only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325499/detect-ios-version-lower-than-ios-8-php

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you have use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

So output is

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone **OS 8_0** like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7

In above output is contains the version of that(see **bold** text on above)

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'OS 8_0') !== false) 
{
    echo "This is iOS 8";
}
else{
    echo "This is not iOS 8";}
}
```

---

Read - [Detecting iOS Version Number from User Agent using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171895/detecting-ios-version-number-from-user-agent-using-regular-expressions)